# Python selenium webdriver "Session not created" exception when opening Chrome

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Here's my code for opening Chrome:

```py
from selenium import webdriver 
driver=webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\Imran\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe')
```

Error when running program:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Imran/PycharmProjects/webscraping/WF Item.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\Imran\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe')
  File "C:\Users\Imran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\Imran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\Imran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\Imran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Imran\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: session not created exception
from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"27028.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.23.409699 (49b0fa931cda1caad0ae15b7d1b68004acd05129),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)
```

Getting the following exception:

```py
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: session not created exception
```

Comment: Did you find a solution ?

Comment: @Romain Jouin Please download update version of chromedriver

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Update your chromedriver to 2.24 version from the given url:

http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.24/

That worked for me.

Comment: I can't really understand how do we update chromedriver ? I have a [chromedriver] in  [ ~/anaconda/bin ] => should I download, unzip and replace the [chromedriver] file with the newly unzipped [chromedriver] file ?

Comment: I'm using apt-get way for installing/updating on my linux sysyem

Answer (score 3):

Setting `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` before executing my script works for me.
See this: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1552#c43

In Python:

```
import os
os.environ["LANG"] = "en_US.UTF-8"
```

Answer (score 1):

To install the chromedriver on windows, download and unzip the chromedriver_win32.zip and add the path to the folder containing the chromedriver.exe in the environment variables setting [System properties - Advanced system settings - Environment variables].