# Updating Chromedriver on Windows

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to update my chromedriver.exe file as outlined here.

[Python selenium webdriver "Session not created" exception when opening Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373801/python-selenium-webdriver-session-not-created-exception-when-opening-chrome)

The problem is, I do not know the location of the old chromedriver on my Windows machine, and therefore can't update.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The installation path would be available in the traceback itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you check you environment variables and look at the path, assuming this already was working, then the path should exist in there, use that to find where it is located.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update to the latest chrome driver, download it and keep that path As a **First Value** (or First row in windows 10) in the PATH, so that the first row will be picked up to look for chromedriver which is latest one.

If you want to remove old driver, (if it was working earlier), then it must be one of the system PATHs. So go through each one.

NORMALLY, people keep the chromedriver in C:\python27\scripts folder (or any python version folder)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can see the path in the constructor:

```
driver=webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Path\\to\\chromedriver.exe')
```

If it's a variable, run in debug and find out the variable value.

Other than that you can simply look for the file in Windows, open  Windows Explorer (WinKey + E), than go to the search (Ctrl + E) and type "chromedriver.exe".

Answer (score 0):

In Command Prompt input -

```
\cd
dir chormedriver.exe /S /P
```

and the path(s) of the location(s) will print/display with other information.