# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: session not created exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, splinter

I am trying to use splinter on my mac version 10.12.4  and for that selenium is necessery , I installed everything properly but when i run my code it open a blank chrome window and then i am getting these two error one by one :

first error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/exepaul/Downloads/pythoncrawling/fix.py", line 14, in <module>
    browser = Browser('chrome')  # open a chrome browser
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/splinter/browser.py", line 63, in Browser
    return driver(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/splinter/driver/webdriver/chrome.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.driver = Chrome(chrome_options=options, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 140, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 229, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 297, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: session not created exception
from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"6860.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.20.353124 (035346203162d32c80f1dce587c8154a1efa0c3b),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.4 x86_64)
```

second error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/exepaul/Downloads/pythoncrawling/fix.py", line 14, in <module>
    browser = Browser('chrome')  # open a chrome browser
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/splinter/browser.py", line 63, in Browser
    return driver(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/splinter/driver/webdriver/chrome.py", line 34, in __init__
    self.driver = Chrome(chrome_options=options, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 140, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 229, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 295, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 464, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 488, in _request
    resp = self._conn.getresponse()
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1197, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 266, in _read_status
    raise RemoteDisconnected("Remote end closed connection without"
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
```

I searched and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373801/python-selenium-webdriver-session-not-created-exception-when-opening-chrome) answer which suggested to update your chromedriver so i installed latest chromedriver and update the path in /etc/paths but still i am getting same error , then i tried to understand the error and i thought maybe its because of session so i tried to create session with requests library in python :

```
import requests
MAX_RETRIES = 20


art="https://www.google.com"
session = requests.Session()
adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=MAX_RETRIES)
session.mount('https://', adapter)
session.mount('http://', adapter)
r = session.get(art)
```

But no luck , I am not getting how to solve this error , my code is :

```
from splinter import Browser
import pandas as pd



url="https://www.google.com"


browser = Browser('chrome')
browser.visit(url)

search_bar_xpath = '//*[@id="lst-ib"]'
search_bar = browser.find_by_xpath(search_bar_xpath)[0]
search_bar.fill("Tony_stark is Iron_Man")


search_button_xpath = '//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[3]/center/input[1]'
search_button = browser.find_by_xpath(search_button_xpath)[0]
search_button.click()


search_results_xpath = '//h3[@class="r"]/a'
search_results = browser.find_by_xpath(search_results_xpath)


scraped_data = []
for search_result in search_results:

    title = search_result.text.encode('utf8')
    link = search_result["href"]
    scraped_data.append((title, link))

df = pd.DataFrame(data=scraped_data, columns=["title", "link"])
df.to_csv("links.csv")
```

Comment: From your error log, i learned your chrome browser is 61  and chromedriver is 2.20.  try chromedriver 2.30,  it worked fine with my Chrome 61,  Maybe latest chromedriver not campatible with Chrome 61

Comment: But how ? even i am trying to use latest chromedriver and changed the path but pycharm (selenium) taking old webdriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue. Since many people face same issue I thought I'll share my solution:

I was updating chromedriver via  `/etc/paths` but the pycharm was showing old version of chrome driver so first I had to uninstall the old chromedriver via :

1. Remove all versions with `brew uninstall --force chromedriver`.
2. Install new version which you can download[here](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.32/).

Now its works perfectly

P.S : One more issued which I fixed: I was not using secure connection while visiting google, so I have to use https://www.google.com instead of http://www.google.com

Answer (score 1):

I thinks your `chromedriver` is not updated Please update it from this link

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/

Also i dont see the path of chromedriver in your code like this

```
from selenium import webdriver 
driver=webdriver.Chrome('D:\\Sankalp_Python\\Python36\\selenium\\chromedriver.exe')
```

Comment: Yes , i tried this driver=webdriver.Chrome('/Users/exepaul/Downloads/chromedriver/chromedriver')
 but no luck.

Comment: Strange but what are the main issue